# how can we store imges path in array in sql

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I am using this code for store the images path in database but its not working
so can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code?Im try to save these images in an array in sql. so what can i do for this . Thanks in advance

```
foreach ($_FILES["image_party"]["error"] as $key => $error) { 
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { 
        $ofname1 = $_FILES["image_party"]["name"][$key]; 
        $fnm1 = $_FILES["image_party"]["tmp_name"][$key]; 
        $location = "../wp-content/plugins/".dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__))."/uploads/".$ofname1; 
        move_uploaded_file($fnm1,$location); 
        CreateimageThumb("../wp-content/plugins/".dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__))."/uploads/".$ofname1,"../wp-content/plugins/".dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__))."/thumbnail/".$ofname1,140,140); 
        $datos_uno=implode(",", $ofname1); 



        $table_name1 = $wpdb->prefix ."pimages"; 
        $query1="INSERT INTO ". $table_name1 . " set storiesid = '".$lid."',partyimg = '".$datos_uno."'"; 
        mysql_query($query1); //echo $query1; exit; //$lid = mysql_insert_id(); //echo $query1; exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: `exit()` stops current script execution so that `mysql_query()` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you are posting a debug version of your code, but there is an `exit` before your sql command... This will prevent the rest of the code from working.

Ok since that was the debug version, change your query like below and try:

```
$query1="INSERT INTO ". $table_name1 . "(storiesid,partyimg) values ('".mysql_real_escape_string($lid)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($datos_uno)."')";
```

Also, as a side note, think about using `mysqli` or `PDO` because `mysql` functions have been deprecated in PHP

Comment: sorry for that ijust check the value of its so i put exit. i just remove this .if you have any sujjestion then pls tell me . thaks

Comment: @sunny: since, that was debug query, I have updated my answer, check if that helps.

Comment: thanks for query. but i can tell you one thing that $datos_uno its so empty ; i just want to know how can we transfer the images path into the array. using with implode

Comment: does `$ofname1` have any value? can you paste what it contains?

Comment: yes $ofname1 have the value when i use to store data in the data base but when we $ofname into the string using impode then its show noting , pls can you guide me

Comment: once again, can you paste what `$ofname1` contains so as to get an idea of why implode is breaking?